# Whats wrong with artikulate?

Tags: applications

With a fresh first install all artikulate would do is show the icon in dock and disapear with no errors or warnings with out starting. So to the terminal I go with `sudo apt-get remove artikulate`, then `sudo apt-get autoremove artikulate`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install artikulate`. Finally I go to launch from the terminal, just in case I have issue hoping it would report back to me whats going on and this is what I get.

```
~$ artikulate
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"

(artikulate:5694): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(artikulate:5694): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(artikulate:5694): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(artikulate:5694): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
log_liblearner: Database path:  "/home/tw/.local/share/artikulate/learnerdata.db"
log_liblearner: No last active profile found, falling back to first found profile
There is no subdirectory "skeletons" in directory  "."  cannot load skeletons.
There is no subdirectory "courses" in directory  "."  cannot load courses.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///usr/share/artikulate/qml/Main.qml:24 module "QtQml.Models" is not installed

KCrash: crashing... crashRecursionCounter = 2
KCrash: Application Name = artikulate path = /usr/bin pid = 5694
KCrash: Arguments: /usr/bin/artikulate 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Although I am not a total noob, I still am not the best at linux. Any recommendations on how to correct this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly the problem on my old laptop with Lubuntu/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a message on [this mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg33041.html) that seems to describe your issue.

It would seem that the solution should be to install "qml-module-qtqml-models2". You could do so with the following command:

```
sudo apt install qml-module-qtqml-models2
```

Comment: You might want to report this bug. at https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos and search for "artikulate" or upstream https://www.kde.org/applications/education/artikulate/development